# My .htaccess file is not working at bluehost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver, bluehost

In my public_html folder at bluehost(runs apache), there is a `.htaccess` folder written like below;

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The `public_html` folder is contained in a home folder, that home folder has no .`htacess` files, I tried to add the one below but no change.

Anyway, I have put a directory into the `public_html` folder, I have called this directory "trials". I have put a `.htaccess` file in this directory, the file is below;

```
Options -Indexes
```

But when I don't have an `index.html` file, it still lists all my files in the "trials" directory in a list format. This is bad as hackers can know everything, how can I stop this? I tried their chat and ended up with someone who couldn't solve it...

Answer (score 0):

```
Options -Indexes
```

You need to add that in your public_html folder. It will not work if you add it in any other folder, it needs to be in public_html